# How to set selected value on select (selectpicker plugin) using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the [Bootstrap-Select](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select) plugin like this:

**HTML/PHP:**

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-normalize="true" id="produtos" name="produtos" onload="buscaProduto(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" onchange="buscaProduto(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <?php require_once("model/produtoModel.php");
          require_once("dao/produtoDao.php");

          $produtoModel = new produtoModel();
          $produtoDao = new produtoDao();

          echo '<option value="0">Selecione um produto</option>';

          //select All
          $models = $produtoDao-> selectAll();
          foreach ($models as $model){
             echo '<option value="'.$model->getId().'">'.$model->getNome().'</option>';
          }

          $produtoModel = null;
          $produtoDao = null;

          ?>
</select>
```

I want to set the value selected to this select when button clicked.

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#tblitens").on("click", "#btnupdateitem", function(e) {
        $('select[name=produtos]').val(249);
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    });
}
```

Nothing happens. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the `val` method of the `selectpicker`:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', '249');
```

Check the following example:

```js
$("#select1").selectpicker();
$("#setval").click(function(){
  $("#select1").selectpicker('val', 2)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<div class="form-group" id="form-group-1">
  <label for="select1">Select list:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="select1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
</div>

<button id="setval">Set value</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Dekel, this solution works. But, I needed to load bootstrap before bootstrap-select too.

Comment: Yes, bootstrap is required for bootstrap-select to work.